# Add Java syntax highlighting to [java-8] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Please can questions tagged [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) be associated with Java-style syntax highlighting? 
Some questions specifically relating to Java 8 features don't include the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag ([list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8+-java)) and it would be nice to see some syntax highlighting.

I note there are a lot of other `[java-*]` language tags (see list below). So I guess either all of these should get the same hint applied, or we should consider this an unmaintainable goal, in which case I won't be offended if we ditch this request.

Tags:

- [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee)
- [java-ee-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-5)
- [java-ee-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-6)
- [java-ee-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-7)
- [java-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-6)
- [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7)
- [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added the hint to the listed tags.

But really, questions having any of these tags should also get a Java tag.