# Please add java language formatting to rx-java tag

Tags: feature-request

A lot of people don't bother tagging their [rx-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rx-java) questions with the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, so their code doesn't look as pretty as it should.

Comment: Language formatting isn't bound to tags?!? Many people simply don't care to use the right code formatting anyways.

Comment: Really? Has the way it works changed since this question? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269051/add-java-syntax-highlighting-to-java-8-tag

I've added the java tag to a few rx-java questions and the syntax highlighting was fixed as a result.

I created this feature request because of this from Jeff Atwood: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/289377

Comment: No, not really. "But really, questions having any of these tags should also get a Java tag."

Comment: Yes, but they don't. "I added the hint to the listed tags."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better fix is to add the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag to those questions. Correct tagging is not just about syntax highlighting; it also gets questions in front of the the right eyeballs. I follow [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), trusting that Java questions are tagged with it irrespective of which particular library or piece of the language they're specifically about.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Yes, it would be nice if everyone who asked RxJava questions tagged their questions with the [tag:java] tag. But they don't. When you say there's a better "fix", do you mean that fix is for someone to monitor the [tag:rx-java] tag and _manually_ add the java tag when it's missing?

Comment: @RobWorsnop: Obviously. It is surprising how much of a mess most first-timers make of tagging. And generally of their question. You can do any and all of those corrections you feel qualified to make on any of those questions you see.

Comment: That's what I mean, yes. I fix tags in nearly every question I view. Probably 1 out of 3 are missing a language tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag you can add the language hint in the Markdown:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
```

before each code block

See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for more details.