# Add Java syntax highlighting to [java-9]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[Java-9 is coming](http://www.java9countdown.xyz/) and the community already have [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9). We have 28 questions tagged with [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9).

I know that we can [explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) override the highlighting or simply add the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag for every question about [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9), but I think it deserves having a highlighter independently of other tags.

Can we have it please?

Comment: Yet another version specific tag with limited, if not detrimental, usefulness.

Comment: Also, the java syntax-highlight is already present for [tag:java-6], [tag:java-7] and [tag:java-8]. This would keep the consistency (related Meta for java-8: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269051/1743880).

Comment: @Braiam I disagree. It's very useful; Java 8 introduced many drastic changes, and the coming Java 9 will change it even more (introducing modularity, JShell and more).

Comment: It seems to me that only the Java tag should have the text highlighting.  Version restrictions would be an additional tag "java java-9".  My concern is that most questions/answers will be applicable to multiple versions, so encouraging everyone to use a different tag will make it harder to find answers.

Comment: @Trisped Users should know when to use what. Java-8 should be used for Java 8 features (lambdas, streams, etc..). Java-9 includes many changes, that are really irrelevant to previous versions.

Comment: @MarounMaroun How do they know to only use Java-9 for features made available in Java-9?  Nothing in the tag tells me that this is the correct usage instead.  Personally, I would use the Java-9 tag to indicate that I am using that version and I need the best solution to my problem restricted to the features available in Java-9.  How do I know that i am using the tag wrong?

Comment: @Trisped You don't know, but many users *do* know and can edit your post to make it better. The [Java-9] tag should be used when you have a problem related to features in Java-9 (the tag should contain information about drastic changes that happened in this version).

Comment: @MarounMaroun The problem is only a few users (of the total SO users) know of this inconsistency with the tagging system.  Usability for all users needs to be a high priority so the site is easier to understand and use for anyone.  What happens when I post an answer using the tags incorrectly (because their abnormal usage conditions are not visible to me), and someone comes and edits my tags so they are correct?  I am going to get upset because (as far as I can tell) they are vandalizing my content.

Comment: @MarounMaroun My concern is that the tags should all follow the same conventions or state how they are used when different then the norm.  The Java-9 tag does not do so, and I expect the other Java tags also do not.  Rather then continuing this difference, I feel we should change the Java tags to match the norm.

Comment: @Trisped is this the same case with [tag:c++11]? It has C++ syntax highlight, though the wiki mentions to also add [tag:c++].

Comment: @Trisped It is already the case for Java-8. Very few people will use the tag without having a specific Java-8 feature question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. `lang-java` is now the default for [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9)